# std::ostream class member variable to be used as std::ofstream or std::ostringstream

Tags: c++, ostream

I'm struggling with streams. I would like to have FileWriter that writes MyObject data to file or to a stringstream. I don't want the interface of write() to take the file path or the stringstream becouse I may have other concrete writers that serialize to some different devices (i.e. socket). So I need to pass the file path or the stringstream to the FileWriter constructor. I need to have a stringstream as an alternative to a filePath so that I can easily implement unit testing.

Here is a sketch of the classes I have described:

```
class IObjectWriter {
virtual void write(MyObject& o) = 0;    
};

class FileWriter : public IObjectWriter {

FileWriter(const std::string& filePath) {
    std::ofstream os(filePath, std::ios::out);
    // assign in some way os to stream member variable
}

FileWriter(std::ostringstream& so) {
    // assign in some way os to stream member variable
}

void write(MyObject& o) override {
    stream << o.getSomeValue();
}   

private:
    std::ostream stream;    
};
```

The problem I could not solve is to "assign" the ofstream and ostringstream to the ostream member so that the write() call can write independently on file or stingstream.

Problems I've run into:

- std::ostream does not have a default constructor
- streams not assignable or copyable
- not able to use the same rdbuf for ofstream and ostringstream

Possible solutions or ideas:

- use shared_ptr for the member variable, but that means the FileWriter constructor should be modified to accept a shared_ptr for the ostringstream.
- I don't think using a std::ostream& for the member variable is a good idea, because of the lifecycle handling of the passes ostringstream

Comment: Is making this a template an option? `template<class StreamType> class FileWriter {};`? Note that **File**Writer seems like a bad name for this kind of class.

Comment: Thanks, I discarded the template solution but thinking it over again I will try.
About the class name, I know, this is just an example code, not the real name ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Why can't you simply have two separate classes - `FileWriter` that writes to an `ofstream`, and `StringWriter` that writes to an `ostringstream`? Let the user decide which type of writer it wants to use, eg:

```cpp
class FileWriter : public IObjectWriter {
public:
    FileWriter(const std::string& filePath) : stream(filePath) { }

    void write(MyObject& o) override {
        stream << o.getSomeValue();
    }   

private:
    std::ofstream stream;
};

class StringWriter : public IObjectWriter {
public:
    StringWriter(std::ostringstream &os) : stream(os) { }

    void write(MyObject& o) override {
        stream << o.getSomeValue();
    }   

private:
    std::ostringstream &stream;
};
```

```
FileWriter fw("path");
fw.write(obj);

std::ostringstream oss;
StringWriter sw(oss);
sw.write(obj);
```

You could then reuse some code by adding a common base class, eg:

```cpp
class StreamWriter : public IObjectWriter {
public:
    StreamWriter(std::ostream& os) : stream(os) { }

    void write(MyObject& o) override {
        stream << o.getSomeValue();
    }   

private:
    std::ostream &stream;
};


class FileWriter : public StreamWriter {
public:
    FileWriter(const std::string& filePath) : StreamWriter(ofs), ofs(filePath) { }

private:
    std::ofstream ofs;
};

class StringWriter : public StreamWriter {
public:
    StringWriter(std::ostringstream &oss) : StreamWriter(oss) { }
};
```

But, in that case, you may as well just use `StreamWriter` by itself, and let the user pass in whatever `ostream`-derived object it wants to write to, eg:

```cpp
std::ofstream ofs("path");
StreamWriter sw1(ofs);
sw1.write(obj);

std::ostringstream oss;
StreamWriter sw2(oss);
sw2.write(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the purpose of having ostringstream and ofstream in the same calss is to make the class unit-testable. If you accept the definition that a unit test should not involve external systems (like a file system).

Comment: All the more reason to not have 1 writer class that has 2 separate responsibilities depending on context (especially when one of them doesn't match the class name). I would stick with just `StreamWriter` where the main code passes in `ofstream` and the unit test passes in `ostringstream`.